# React Bootstrap accordion defaultActiveKey not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap

I've created a sandbox example to show what the problem is:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-accordion-14pcp

---

I am setting up an accordion with a defaultActiveKey but is not working.
Here's the code I use to set an active class when an item is clicked. Where `useState("2")` is what should be the defaultActiveKey.

```
  const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState("2");

  function toggleActive(id) {
    if (activeId === id) {
      setActiveId(null);
    } else {
      setActiveId(id);
    }
  }
```

I am then rendering it like so:

```
  <Accordion defaultActiveKey={activeId}>
    {faq.questions.map((question, index) => {
      return (
        <Card className="rounded-lg mb-3 border-0" key={index}>
          <Accordion.Toggle
            as={Card.Header}
            eventKey={index + 1}
            onClick={() => toggleActive(index + 1)}
            className={activeId === index + 1 ? "active" : null}
          >
            {question.title}
          </Accordion.Toggle>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={index + 1}>
            <Card.Body>
              <p className="text-muted">{question.text}</p>
            </Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
      );
    })}
  </Accordion>
```

`faq.questions` is an array which holds some data. I also had to add +1 to each index `{index + 1}` to make it work otherwise the first accordion item does not work.

The funny thing is that if I set this up without the `.map()` and do them with no dynamic code it works e.g.:

```
  <Accordion defaultActiveKey={activeId}>
    <Card className="rounded-lg mb-3 border-0">
      <Accordion.Toggle
        as={Card.Header}
        eventKey="0"
        onClick={() => toggleActive("0")}
        className={activeId === "0" ? "active" : null}
      >
        Question
      </Accordion.Toggle>
      <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
        <Card.Body>
          <p className="text-muted">
            Answer
          </p>
        </Card.Body>
      </Accordion.Collapse>
    </Card>
  </Accordion>
```

Comment: Is `activeId` meant to be a string or a number? You're setting it as a string in the `useState` but then making operations and checks as if it's a number in the rest of the code.

Comment: `activeId` is supposed to be number. When I remove the mapping and 'hard-code' everything it works. by removing mapping I mean `faq.questions.map((question, index) =>` removing this and do not map the accordion and just create like 3 more `<Card className="rounded-lg mb-3 border-0">` as per the example in the bottom of my post.

Comment: I have created a quick Sandbox example to show what's happening:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-accordion-14pcp?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: If `activeId` is meant to be a number then initialize it as such: `const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(2);`. Don't use a string.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I completely overlooked that one and could not wrap my brain around it. It was indeed meant to be a number and not a string.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming along in the future, react-bootstrap's Accordion's `defaultActiveKey` no longer takes a number, it takes a string or array of strings. [See source code here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/AccordionContext.ts#L3).

Copy/paste of the line for future sake if it ever changes.

```
export type AccordionEventKey = string | string[] | null | undefined;
```

In order to get these values set, especially if you want multiple or all of your accordions opened at the start, you'll have to create an array of strings, one for each step you want.

This can be done like so

```
const keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"];

return (
    <Accordion defaultActivekey={[...Array(keys.length).keys()].map(a => String(a))}>
        {keys.map((body, index) => (
            <Accordion.Item eventKey={`${index}`}>
                <Accordion.Header>
                    Step {index + 1}
                </Accordion.Header>
                <Accordion.Body>{body}</Accordion.Body>
            </Accordion.Item>
        ))}
    </Accordion>
)
```

You can also extract the logic out to a function and use that instead of the ugly code.

```
/**
 * Produces an array of strings for 0 to obj.length, e.g. my_arr.length = 3, produces ['0', '1', '2'].
 * @param obj Array of strings
 * @returns Array of strings of the stringified length of obj
 */
function lenToStrArr(obj: Array<string>): string[] {
    return [...Array(obj.length).keys()].map(a => String(a));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace eventKey={i} to eventKey={`${i}`}

///////////
WORKING CODE
///////////////

```
            <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
              {
                 faqLists?.map((ele,i)=>{
                  return(
                    <Accordion.Item eventKey={`${i}`}>
                    <Accordion.Header>{ele.faq_title}</Accordion.Header>
                    <Accordion.Body>{ele.faq_description}</Accordion.Body>
                  </Accordion.Item>
                  )
                 }
                 )
                 }

            </Accordion>
```